# What is the practical use of list.clear() method in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I was wondering why I would need to use `list.clear()` method instead of creating a new list. Except for **memory allocation** and a few other cases where I would need an empty list at the start of each iteration and have to do some operations on the list elements, why would I need to use the `clear()` method?

Even it looks like it is more efficient to create a new list rather than using `clear()` method.

```py
import dis
def create_new_list():
    l = []

def clear_list(l):
    l.clear()

dis.dis(create_new_list)
1  0 RESUME               0

2  2 BUILD_LIST           0
   4 STORE_FAST           0 (a)
   6 LOAD_CONST           0 (None)

dis.dis(clear_list)
1  0 RESUME               0

2  2 LOAD_FAST            0 (l)
   4 LOAD_METHOD          0 (clear)
   26 PRECALL             0
   30 CALL                0
   40 POP_TOP
   42 LOAD_CONST          0 (None)
   44 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: old list must le collected by the garbade collector and then destroyed. this operation is not reflected when you're creating new list everytime

Comment: @Vishal Singh If we keep garbage collection and deletion of the list aside, is there a case, where using `list.clear()` would make more sense than creating a new list? I know a few situations where a list is being referenced at multiple locations and deleting it may create chaos. But what if I do not delete any references? I am not taking memory utilization thing in picture for now and the garbage collector will clean the mess when my program ends completely